VLAN or different option?
I have a problem and a request for a solution. I have four network devices, each with the same IP address 169.254.1.1.
These network devices have DHCP enabled from 169.254.1.4 - 20. I can also connect using manual IP address ex 169.254.1.4.
I have one mother computer that would like to communicate with them through addresses in the range of 192.168.1.x.
If I buy a router can I configure it so that for example:
host1 169.254.1.1 -> 169.254.1.4 -> 192.168.1.10 
host2 169.254.1.1 -> 169.254.1.4 -> 192.168.1.20 
host3 169.254.1.1 -> 169.254.1.4 -> 192.168.1.30 
host4 169.254.1.1 -> 169.254.1.4 -> 192.168.1.40

and the mother computer when it wants to talk to host#1 will use the address 192.168.1.10?
TP-Link ER605 Router

maybe otherwise will show the problem. I'm not an expert in networking :). nothing can be changed in the settings and addressing. a network device has a diagnostic address of 169.254.1.1 You can use this diagnostic port for other things and control the device. i would like to "controller" to control 4 devices, I can even connect to each device a router, bridge whatever so that I can connect to each device on a different address. I just need a specific port xxxx e.g. 9999 forward.I can from the controller without a problem to get to one device, but how to do it to connect another 3.I can not change addresses in the network device in the controller I can freely change and the controller has only one network interface.Is it possible ? What to use ?

You should read RFC 3927. Link local is link local, and those addresses are not routable by definition.

Your problem seems to be so far away from VLANs so I can't even imagine how you got the idea to use them. Don't use addresses 169.254.x.x; those are "IPv4LL" — unroutable, automatically assigned, stateless link local addresses. If you want to route, assign routable addresses — it can well be private addresses like 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x, assigned statically or dynamically (DHCP).
If you have many systems that need to communicate, build a proper network plan and avoid situations where several systems have the same IP address. That's the first thing you have to do, instead of buying something. That's how you decide what to buy, by the way.
